# Sharepoint linq throws error

Tags: client-object-model

I know this is a common problem and there are lots of suggestions on the internet, but non of them helped me to sort this issue out.

I have created my data context class by using SPMetal.exe tool.

I have created a console application with the configuration below

CPU: Any CPU
Framework: .net 3.5

I tried to test whether my datacontext is working fine or now via the lines below,

```
  IMG.CustomerPortal.Data.Context.IMGContextDataContext con = new IMG.CustomerPortal.Data.Context.IMGContextDataContext("http://server/site_name/");
        EntityList<TicketItem> lst = con.GetList<TicketItem>("ListName");

        Console.WriteLine(lst.First().ClosedDate);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

it throws  an error below;

> The Web application at http://server/site_name/ could not be found. Verify that you have typed the URL correctly. If the URL should be serving existing content, the system administrator may need to add a new request URL mapping to the intended application.

However, in same project, I am able to access to the data via client object model by using the code below;

```
 string siteUrl = "http://server/site_name/";

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
        Web oWebsite = clientContext.Web;
        ListCollection collList = oWebsite.Lists;

        clientContext.Load(collList);

        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var oList in collList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Title: {0} Created: {1}", oList.Title, oList.Created.ToString());
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong here? it does not seem to be related to framework version or architecture.

is there anything missing, or any idea why it throws this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you should open console application project properties, go to the Build tab and select x64 in platform target dropdown list.

Also you should check that you runs your console application on the mashine that hosts Server/Site_Name.

Comment: nope.. I tried it already and gave another try after your reply.. still same, I am afraid..

Comment: it is a stupid question... but are you sure that you runs your application on the pc that hosts the http://server/site_name/ ?

Comment: do I need to though?

Comment: you are right, I moved it to server and it worked.. do I have to work on the same machine as the Sharepoint is running on to use linq?

Comment: yes. You should use it in the same mashine.

Comment: that is bad:( anyway, could you post your reply as answer so that I will mark it as answer

Comment: No that's not bad, because you can use the REST API instead which works a lot better that the buggy LINQ provider. Add a  web reference to  http://server/site_name/_vti_bin/listdata.svc

Comment: @PerJakobsen I decided to use rest API.. it seems indeed better..

Comment: @Alexander Could you add your comment as answer so that I can mark it as answered.

Comment: I updated my answer, you can mark it as answered :)